# How do I use depth first search to solve this puzzle?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, search, breadth-first-search

So what I did was take a sliding puzzle that looks like this:

```
1 0 3
4 2 6
7 5 8
```

Where 0 represents the empty space and I turned it into a graph via an adjacency matrix. What I then want to do is search through the graph and find the value that's 0 and then starting from that value, perform a DFS and find a path from 0 to the bottom right corner when the solved puzzle would look like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 0
```

Here's the code which is supposed to perform the DFS:

```
public static boolean SolveNinePuzzle(int[][] B){
        //first section of the code makes the adjacency matrix
        int[][] G = new int[9][9];
        int temp2;
        int temp1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                getBoardFromIndex(i);
                if (i < 2){
                    temp1 = B[i][j];
                    temp2 = B[i+1][j];
                    G[temp2][temp1] = 1;
                    G[temp1][temp2] = 1;
                    getIndexFromBoard(B);
                }
                if (i > 0){
                    temp1 = B[i][j];
                    temp2 = B[i-1][j];
                    G[temp2][temp1] = 1;
                    G[temp1][temp2] = 1;
                    getIndexFromBoard(B);
                }
                if (j < 2){
                    temp1 = B[i][j];
                    temp2 = B[i][j+1];
                    G[temp2][temp1] = 1;
                    G[temp1][temp2] = 1;
                    getIndexFromBoard(B);
                }
                if (j > 0){
                    temp1 = B[i][j];
                    temp2 = B[i][j-1];
                    G[temp2][temp1] = 1;
                    G[temp1][temp2] = 1;
                    getIndexFromBoard(B);
                }
            }
        }
        printGraph(G);
        System.out.println();
        //Finds out where 0 is and moves the tiles either up down or left or right depending on
        int l = B.length;
        int temp;
        boolean isSolved = true;
        printBoard(B);
        int n = G.length;
        int[] visited = new int[n];
        int visits = 0;
        int c = 0; 
        visited[c] = 1;
        for (int k = 0; k < visited.length; k++) {
            if (visited[k] == 0 && G[c][k] == 1){
                visited[c] = 1;
                c = k;
                k = 0;
            }
        }
```

Now it's supposed to go through all the adjacent vertices. What I don't have yet is a way to swap values on the board and I also don't have the search stop when it reaches the bottom right corner. Basically, how can I apply the DFS algorithm on the graph with the board.

Comment: In my any implementation of a BFS, it always comes with a queue(normal queue or priority queue). I think you would better learn something about queue(not so hard) and implement a BFS.

Comment: I added the DFS code without stacks so is it actually possible to do BFS without queues? If it's not possible i'll use queues but first I want to know if it is possible.

Comment: As far as I see impossible. You may post another question on SO:`Is it possible implement a BFS without queue?`

Comment: @JohnKyle, there is no thing as DFS without stacks or BFS without queues. The DFS implementation you gave uses System stack, which is result of `recursion`, so we don't need to define stack explicitly. Since any function call creates a system stack (See, how a code executes, or what happens when a function is called), and there is no (inherent) way to use queue, a queue **will** always be declared in an implementation of BFS.

Answer (score 4):

Repeat from comment:

There is no thing as DFS without stacks or BFS without queues. The DFS implementation you gave uses System stack, which is result of recursion, so we don't need to define stack explicitly. Since any function call creates a system stack (See, how a code executes, or what happens when a function is called), and there is no (inherent) way to use queue, a queue will always be declared in an implementation of BFS.

Now, as you want to solve this using BFS, here is what I recommend:

Firstly, create a array for visited states, so that, you don't make redundant calls every time. There are 9! possibilities which can be stored as string (key), (bool) value mapped, which says whether a board state is visited or not.

Mark the initial state as visited. There can be 2(corner), 3(side) or 4(center) moves that can be made for every board state. Make those moves and push those states in the queue, popping out the current state (and marking it visited). Do this until you get the target state. BFS will, by itself, make certain that if you reach the target state, it will be, in minimum moves.

Comment: Ok so I updated my code again to try a different approach of DFS. The problem I'm still having is, how do I implement the DFS in that graph onto my board?

Comment: Why do you want to solve this using dfs? I think bfs is a better solution... And I'm not sure if dfs will solve this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is tagged, "breadth-first-search," but you are mentioning the acronym, DFS, a lot, perhaps some clarification is needed.

Let's say our game had only two moves possible (1,2) at any board-state (B) and a maximum of three moves were needed to solve each game. Now, how would DFS and BFS differ? In the example below, a "move" is represented in code as a resulting board state; for your game, we could use a string, for example, `"508612347"`, which would also allow us to create a hash to check if that state was already visited and avoid repeating the same search. (Another way to store the board state can be three 27 bit numbers, where each nine bits show which number is currently in that board position. Then the move generation and end test could be done with bitmasks.)

Depth first uses a stack (last in, first out):

```
starting board-state: B

push possible moves to stack

stack: {B1,B2}

pop B2, push possible moves

stack: {B1,B21,B22}

pop B22, push third move

stack: {B1,B21,B221,B222}

pop B222, it's a third move so check for win
```

As you can see, in DFS, using the stack, we are searching one path at a time all the way to its end.

Breadth first uses a queue (first in, first out):

```
starting board-state: B

enqueue possible moves

queue: {B2,B1}

pop B1, enqueue possible moves

queue: {B12,B11,B2}

pop B2, enqueue possible moves

queue: {B22,B21,B12,B11}

...etc.
```

In a BFS, using the queue, we expand all nodes at each level/depth, then move to the next depth.

Without a heuristic to tell us which board states (nodes) are better positioned to lead to the solution, I'm not sure how to tell which of DFS and BFS would be a better base strategy for the 8 puzzle. Perhaps one possible heuristic might be to consider boards with ordered prefixes as closer to the goal.